# Scss (live scss compiler) throws an error when using the imported variables from another scss file (@use)

Tags: sass

this is a strange error that I don't understand at all. I usually search and seek the answer before posting it on StackOverflow. So the problem is that I would like to use the variables that I imported from another scss file called **_variables.com** using **@use**. This is written in [scss-lang.com@use](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use). The way I try to use my variable:

```
_variables.scss
$secondary-color: #CEA44A;

style.scss
@use '../../variables';

.foo {
  background-color: variables.$secondary-color;
}

// ERROR TEXT
Invalid CSS after "...olor: variables": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".$secondary-color;"
on line 19 of sass/c:\Users\Amirreza Amini\Desktop\blog\src\Components\Register\Register.scss
background-color: variables.$secondary-color;
```

Comment: This looks fine to me. Is this the exact code you are using? Is there anything around that `background-color` and it could be the culprit for this error? Try adding alias for that `@use`, to ensure that it is getting the `$secondary-color` from this file and not from some other "variable" file you might also import somewhere else

Comment: @metodribic That wasn't useful.

Comment: I'm just trying to point out possible issues that are maybe not included/described above...

Comment: Are you using `dart-sass`?

Comment: @Arkellys, I'm not sure if I do or not. I don't know any about dart-sass.

Comment: You should check, it's a SASS compiler and `@use` is only compatible with `dart-sass` right now.

Comment: @Arkellys how do I check that?

Comment: What do you use to compile your code? Take a look into your `package.json` if you have one.

Comment: @Arkellys it's already written in the title of the question. VSC Live sass compiler.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the title. Maybe you are not using the right extension then? https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/issues/564

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use Live Sass Compiler by Glenn Marks

I had exactly the same problem. You read about [`@use`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use) on SASS official website, follow the instructions, write the code in Visual Studio Code and then you get this strange `Compilation Error` when saving the SASS or SCSS file. You double check everything and it seems like it should work but it doesn't.

**Well, the problem is caused by the Visual Studio Code extension you are using for compiling SASS or SCSS files to CSS files.**

### Don't use this extension: Live Sass Compiler by Ritwick Dey

You are probably using this extension: [Live Sass Compiler by Ritwick Dey](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass).
It's widely used, but no longer supported by the author. Consequently, the SASS version isn't updated. This extension produces the error you are describing as you can see below.

[image: Wrong extension]

### Use this extension: Live Sass Compiler by Glenn Marks

You should use this extension: [Live Sass Compiler by Glenn Marks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=glenn2223.live-sass). As the author states: *A big thank you to @ritwickdey for all his work. However, as they are no longer maintaining the original work, I have released my own which has built upon it.* This extension compiles your SASS or SCSS files to CSS files successfully as you can see below.

[image: Right extension]

Comment: 80 reputation in a day lol. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

change `@use '../../variables';` to `@use '../../variables' as *;`

Comment: Still giving the same error.